Solving challenging 4D integrals arising from triangle-triangle gravitational interaction
I am trying to find a closed form for two related integrals, coming from a physics problem partially solved here, about attractive forces between two triangles :
$$\begin{align}
  {\bf F}_1  &= -G \int \int \int \int &\frac{{\bf r}_1(t,s)-{\bf r}_2(u,v)}{\|{\bf r}_1(t,s)-{\bf r}_2(u,v)\|^3} (\lambda_1 2 A_1 t) (\lambda_2 2 A_2 u)\, {\rm d}t\,{\rm d}s\, {\rm d}u\, {\rm d}v \\
  {\bf M}_1  &= -G \int \int \int \int {\bf r}_1 \times &\frac{{\bf r}_1(t,s)-{\bf r}_2(u,v)}{\|{\bf r}_1(t,s)-{\bf r}_2(u,v)\|^3} (\lambda_1 2 A_1 t) (\lambda_2 2 A_2 u)\, {\rm d}t\,{\rm d}s\, {\rm d}u\, {\rm d}v 
\end{align} $$
Where ${\bf r}_1$ and ${\bf r}_2$ represent the points in the triangles 1 and 2, respectively:
$$ \begin{align}
 {\bf r}_1(t,s) &= (1-t) {\bf r}_{A} + t (1-s) {\bf r}_{B} + t s {\bf r}_{C}\\
 {\bf r}_2(u,v) &= (1-u) {\bf r}_{D} + u (1-v) {\bf r}_{E} + u v {\bf r}_{F}
\end{align} $$
$G, A_1, A_2, \lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are constants.
I assume that the limits are $0$ and $1-s$ for $t$,  $0$ and $1-v$ for $u$, and 0 to 1 for $s$ and $v$.
I attempted to use a CAS to evaluate these integrals, specifically trying Derive and SymPy. However, maybe due to my limited experience with these toolsI wasn't able to obtain meaningful results.
Any insights, suggestions, or partial solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

\iiiint gives $\iiiint$. However, when the dimensions get that high, people generally stop  using repetion of the integral symbol to indicate higher-dimensional integration: $$\int F(t,s,u,v),dt,ds,du,dv$$ would be understood just fine.

I couldn't really find a closed form, I even found the explicit form for the integrand using Sympy and it is a complete monster to integrate. I'm just going to offer you a (maybe?) simpler form of your integral in polar coordinates.

$\mathbf{\underline{Mutual\ force\ integral}:}$
Let's treat the mutual force integral first. Let's rewrite it in cartesian coordinates:
$$\mathbf F_1=-G\iint_{A_2}\iint_{A_1}\dfrac{\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|^3}\lambda_1\lambda_2\,\mathrm dA_1\,\mathrm dA_2$$
Notice
$$\dfrac{\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|^3}=\boldsymbol\nabla_{\mathbf r_2}\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|}$$
Therefore,
$$-G\iint_{A_2}\lambda_2\boldsymbol\nabla_{\mathbf r_2}\iint_{A_1}\dfrac{\lambda_1}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|}\,\mathrm dA_1\,\mathrm dA_2 \qquad\qquad (\ast)$$
Now we can try and expand $\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|}$ for $\mathbf r_1<\mathbf r_2$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|}&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r_1^2-2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+r_2^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{r_2\sqrt{1-2\dfrac{r_1}{r_2}\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+\left(\dfrac{r_1}{r_2}\right)^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{r_2}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty P_\ell(\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2))\left(\dfrac{r_1}{r_2}\right)^\ell
\end{aligned}$$
Moreover, by the addition theorem we know
$$P_\ell(\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2))=\dfrac{4\pi}{2\ell +1}\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_1,0)\,\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,0)$$
and hence
$$\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|}=\dfrac{1}{r_2}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \dfrac{4\pi}{2\ell +1}\left(\dfrac{r_1}{r_2}\right)^\ell\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_1,0)\,\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,0)$$
Rearraging we obtain
$$-4\pi G\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell\dfrac{\mathcal I_{m\ell}\boldsymbol{\mathcal J}_{m\ell}}{2\ell +1}$$
where
$$\mathcal I_{m\ell}=\iint_{A_1}\lambda_1 r_1^\ell\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_1,0)\,\mathrm dA_1$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{\mathcal J}_{m\ell}&=\iint_{A_2}\lambda_2\boldsymbol\nabla_{\mathbf r_2}\dfrac{\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,0)}{r_2^{\ell+1}}\,\mathrm dA_2\\
&=\iint_{A_2}\dfrac{\lambda_2}{r_2^{\ell+2}}\left[-(\ell+1)\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,0)\,\mathbf e_r+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta_2}\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,0)\,\mathbf e_\theta\right]\,\mathrm dA_2\\
&=-\mathbf i\iint_{A_2}\dfrac{\lambda_2}{r_2^{\ell+2}}\left[(\ell+1)\cos\theta_2\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,0)+\sin\theta_2\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta_2}\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,0)\right]\,\mathrm dA_2\\
&\qquad+\mathbf j\iint_{A_2}\dfrac{\lambda_2}{r_2^{\ell+2}}\left[-(\ell+1)\sin\theta_2\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,0)+\cos\theta_2\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta_2}\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,0)\right]\,\mathrm dA_2
\end{aligned}$$
Finally, you can solve them employing polar coordinates or parametrizing like in that post. But note that in the second case the limits of integration for both triangles are $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and not the ones you said. Furthermore, I'm not sure about the exact expression for $\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_i,0)$ since the addition theorem in $2$D might not be as easy as giving a value to the $3$D theorem... I've read that the $2D$ spherical harmonics are actually the Fourier basis and the normalization factor needn't be $\dfrac{4\pi}{2\ell+1}$ then. So for now I'd just leave it like that.
$\mathbf{\underline{Torque\ integral}:}$
For this integral we've many options. The first one would be applying a similar method to the one we used to get $(\ast)$. Note
$$\dfrac{\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|^3}=-\boldsymbol\nabla_{\mathbf r_1}\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|}$$
It follows that
$$\mathbf M_1=+G\iint_{A_1}\lambda_1\,\mathbf r_1\times\boldsymbol\nabla_{\mathbf r_1}\iint_{A_2}\dfrac{\lambda_2}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|}\,\mathrm dA_2\,\mathrm dA_1$$
Expanding again and following the same exact procedure we arrive at
$$+4\pi G\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell\dfrac{\tilde{\mathcal I}_{m\ell}\tilde{\boldsymbol{\mathcal J}}_{m\ell}}{2\ell +1}$$
where
$$\tilde{\mathcal I}_{m\ell}=\iint_{A_2}\dfrac{\lambda_2}{r_2^{\ell+1}}\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2)\,\mathrm dA_2$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
\tilde{\boldsymbol{\mathcal J}}_{m\ell}&=\iint_{A_1}\lambda_1\mathbf r_1\times\boldsymbol\nabla_{\mathbf r_1}\left(r_1^\ell\,\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_1)\right)\,\mathrm d A_1\\
&=\iint_{A_1}\lambda_1 r_1^{\ell-1}\mathbf r_1\times\left(\mathbf e_r\,\ell \,\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_1)+\mathbf e_\theta\,\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1}\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_1)\right)\,\mathrm d A_1\\
&=\mathbf k\iint_{A_1}\lambda_1 r_1^{\ell}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1}\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_1)\,\mathrm d A_1
\end{aligned}$$
Otherwise the other method was computing the cross product first hand:
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf M_1&=-G\iint_{A_2}\iint_{A_1}\mathbf r_1\times\dfrac{\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|^3}\lambda_1\lambda_2\,\mathrm dA_1\,\mathrm dA_2\\
&=+G\iint_{A_2}\iint_{A_1}\dfrac{\mathbf r_1\times\mathbf r_2}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|^3}\lambda_1\lambda_2\,\mathrm dA_1\,\mathrm dA_2\\
&=+\mathbf k\,G\iint_{A_2}\iint_{A_1}\dfrac{r_1 r_2\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|^3}\lambda_1\lambda_2\,\mathrm dA_1\,\mathrm dA_2
\end{aligned}$$
And then approximating the cubed term like
$$\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|^3}=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \mathcal C_\ell^{(\frac{3}{2})}(\hat{\mathbf r}_1\cdot\hat{\mathbf r}_2)\dfrac{r_1^\ell}{r_2^{\ell+3}}$$
The problem is that I haven't found a way to separate variables for the Gegenbauer polynomials using addition theorem.

$\mathbf{EDIT:}$ I just found another expression for your torque integral which might or might not be easier to compute. Using
$$\boldsymbol\nabla\times\left(\dfrac{\mathbf a}{\phi}\right)=-\mathbf a\times\boldsymbol\nabla\dfrac{1}{\phi}$$
we get
$$-G\int_2\boldsymbol\nabla_2\times\left[\int_1\dfrac{\lambda_1\mathbf r_1}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|}\,\mathrm dA_1\right]\,\lambda_2\,\mathrm dA_2$$

$\mathbf{EDIT\ 2:}$ It might interest you that I found the Gegenbauer addition theorem by pure coincidence:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\small C^{(\lambda)}_{n}\left(\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}+\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{%
2}\cos\phi\right)\\
&\small=\sum_{\ell=0}^{n}2^{2\ell}(n-\ell)!\frac{2\lambda+2\ell-1}{2%
\lambda-1}\frac{({\left(\lambda\right)_{\ell}})^{2}}{{\left(2\lambda\right)_{n%
+\ell}}}(\sin\theta_{1})^{\ell}C^{(\lambda+\ell)}_{n-\ell}\left(\cos\theta_{1}%
\right)(\sin\theta_{2})^{\ell}C^{(\lambda+\ell)}_{n-\ell}\left(\cos\theta_{2}%
\right)C^{(\lambda-\frac{1}{2})}_{\ell}\left(\cos\phi\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

+1 Thank you so much for your response. I read it carefully and thought about it a lot. I'm interested in a fast computation these quantities, and it seems there's no option but to do it approximately.
I feel that a spherical harmonics expansion might not be ideal for a triangle, given how different triangles and spheres are. It might require too many terms for a good representation, especially for small distances between triangles. Do you agree?

Yes, you're right, but otherwise you'd have to solve something of the sort
$$\int_{[0,1]^4} \dfrac{\lambda_1\lambda_2 u t}{[f(u,uv,u^2,u^2v,u^2v^2,t,tu,tuv,t^2,st,stu,stuv,st^2,s^2t^2)]^{\frac{3}{2}}},\mathrm d^2A_1,\mathrm d^2A_2$$
Notice, though that the spherical harmonics are in $2$D, and in these dimensions they're a linear combination of sines and cosines, so it might be easier to compute.

Moreover, I read a book on the internet where they computed the gravitational potential energy between two $3$D bodies and the integral they had to solve was really similar.  They solved it doing a multipole expansion like me and ended up with $4$ summaitions of special functions and long coefficients. So I doubt this one can be any simpler...
